# Issue with SW_HIDE for chrome it didn't work

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

i tried a lot to make this code to work,but with no chance.

i want to run a link example: www.yahoo.com in chrome but in hidden mode using sw_hide for a moment of time and this is my code :

```
Imports System.IO

Imports Microsoft.Win32

Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Imports System.Diagnostics

Imports System.Threading

Module Module1

Const SW_HIDE As Integer = 0
Const SW_RESTORE As Integer = 9
Const SW_MINIMIZE As Integer = 6
Const SW_SHOWMINIMIZED As Integer = 2
Dim hWnd As Integer = 0
 <DllImport("User32")> Private Function ShowWindow(ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal       nCmdShow   As Integer) As Integer
End Function

Sub main()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
    Dim ProcessProperties As New ProcessStartInfo
    ProcessProperties.FileName = "chrome"
    ProcessProperties.Arguments = "www.yahoo.com"
    Dim myProcess As Process = Process.Start(ProcessProperties)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    Call Chm()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
    Call shwo()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
End Sub
Sub Chm()
    Dim p As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome")
    hWnd = p(0).MainWindowHandle.ToInt32
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE)
End Sub
Sub shwo()
    If Not hWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
        ' is app window found?
        ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED)
    End If
End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: The ShowWindow declaration is wrong, hwnd is an IntPtr, return value is Boolean.  Error checking is not optional.

Comment: so, what do you Suggests?

Comment: i did this, but i could not show the window again:Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As SHOW_WINDOW) As Boolean